# Implementing new typeahead with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, typeahead.js

This question relates to the new standalone typeahead that Twitter recently released, not the Bootstrap version.

[Twitter Typeahead.js](http://engineering.twitter.com/2013/02/twitter-typeaheadjs-you-autocomplete-me.html)

I'm trying to integrate this into a rails app to lookup the name of some posts from the db and I'm having trouble trying to get it to work. When I search nothing happens but I can navigate to /posts.json and get data.

I have a working version with hardcoded data you can see in action here, type 'a' to get results:

[jsFiddle local version](http://jsfiddle.net/v7dJ4/1/embedded/result/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'posts',
  prefetch: '/posts.json',
  limit: 10
 });
});
```

**Input**

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" dir="ltr" placeholder="Search here....">
```

Here's my Controller:

```
def names
  names = []
  all = Post.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
  all.each { |subc| names << subc.name }

render json: names
```

end

Params setting:

```
Started GET "/sub_categories/names?q=a" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-15 09:45:40 -0400
Processing by SubCategoriesController#names as JSON
  Parameters: {"q"=>"a"}
  SubCategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "sub_categories".* FROM "sub_categories" WHERE (name LIKE '%%') LIMIT 10
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: And what is currently happening? Is it just not working? Are you getting data from /posts.json?

Comment: I'm getting nothing but I can navigate to /posts.json and get data.

Comment: Ok, I made some progress. I now get results when I search but I'm getting the entire array instead of results just for the letter typed. See controller code added in original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get prefetch to work but I got remote to work by adding "?q=%QUERY" on to the end of the json source:

`remote: '../sub_categories/names?q=%QUERY'`

Then on the query I found out that you have to omit the first '%' so it matches what you type.

Controller:

`Post.where("name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ?", "#{params[:q]}%")`

Comment: what if we want to display the email as well as the name ?